# Registry key list different when executed from Python

Tags: python, batch-file, registry

I tried to execute the same entry from `cmd` and also from a `python` script. But apparently the results retrieved from Python was a subset of the list retrieved from the command prompt execution. Any pointers on the same? Is it something related to permissions?

Executed in cmd:-

```
    reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE & timeout /t 7
```

Python script :-

```
def list_registry():
    os.system(r"reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE & timeout /t 7")
```

Any references would be highly helpful.  Thanks in advance ! :-)

**Edit:**

I found that when executed from Python the

```
inst_loc = C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory
```

and from cmd it's

```
inst_loc =C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory
```

Comment: This is strange. I tried your example but with other entry and for me all works the same. Are you run python script from cmd of another way? May be you want to use _winreg? https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html

Comment: I tried the same - not sure what's happening. One interesting fact to be noted is that when run from python it's not the administrator prompt which is invoked. Not sure if it's directly related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer figured out ... I was using the 32bit Python so that didn't retrieve the complete list of registry entries. Switched to 64bit and it displays all. Closing thread.